# Converting Centigrade to Fahrenheit using variables C or F of using a method in java

Tags: java, input, output

I am creating a method called convertTemp(...) in java that takes a value , tempF,for the temperature in Fahrenheit as an input and convert the value into Centigrade (C) and displays its on screen. The formula for the conversion from Fahrenheit F to Centigrade C is C = 5/9*(F-32).  The issue is I want to know what is my mistake of my code that cannot run in the eclipse.

```
package oop;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class convertTemp {

public static int temperature (int C , int F) {

     int Fahrenheit =5/9*(F-32);
    return Fahrenheit;
}
public static void main (String args []) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int F ;

    int C ;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" The temperature of Fahrenheit(F) : ");

    F = sc.nextInt();

    System.out .println(" The temperature of Centigrade(C) : " + C );
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Well, you're not calling your `temperature` method, for a start...

Comment: You never called your method. Also, your method takes 2 parameters but you are only using 1 of them which you may want to look into.

Comment: And your `temperature` method looks a bit confusing, in that it ignores the `C` value, and creates a `Fahrenheit` local variable from `F`. Is it meant to be a Celsius-to-Fahrenheit converter or vice versa?

Comment: Also `int Fahrenheit =5/9*(F-32);` will work differently than you'd expect.

Comment: It may also be useful to read about java coding conventions. See oracle's article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

First of all you're not calling the method anywhere, so no code is executed there.
Secondly, I don't really know why your method `temperature` needs two parameters. Normally, you'd only need to enter a single value (in °F or °C) and get a result (in °C or °F).

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
public static double toCelsius(double fahrenheit) {
    return 5.0 / 9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
}
```

Note the use of the type `double` as well as the use of `double` literals. Otherwise you'll end up doing [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0) which will give you wrong results.

To be able to do the reverse calculation, you'll need a second method:

```
public static double toFahrenheit(double celsius) {
    // do your logic
}
```

Then in your `main` class, you actually have to *call* those methods to see their effects.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double f = sc.nextDouble();
    double c = sc.nextDouble();

    double cResult = toCelsius(f);
    System.out.println(f + "°F is " + cResult + "°C");

    double fResult = toFahrenheit(c);
    System.out.println(c + "°C is " + fResult + "°F");
}
```